# PowerShell run script simultaneously

Tags: powershell

I created a PowerShell script to remove all files and folders older than X days. This works perfectly fine and the logging is also ok. Because PowerShell is a bit slow, it can take some time to delete these files and folders when big quantities are to be treated.

My questions: How can I have this script ran on multiple directories ($Target) at the same time?

Ideally, we would like to have this in a scheduled task on Win 2008 R2 server and have an input file (txt, csv) to paste some new target locations in.

Thank you for your help/advise.

**The script**

```
#================= VARIABLES ==================================================
$Target = \\share\dir1"
$OlderThanDays = "10"
$Logfile = "$Target\Auto_Clean.log"

#================= BODY =======================================================
# Set start time
$StartTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()

Write-Output "`nDeleting folders that are older than $OlderThanDays days:`n" | Tee-Object $LogFile -Append 

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $Target | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | ForEach {
        $Folder = $_.FullName
        Remove-Item $Folder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()      
        # If folder can't be removed
        if (Test-Path $Folder)
        { "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Folder (IN USE)" } 
        else
        { "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Folder" }  
        } | Tee-Object $LogFile -Append # Output folder names to console & logfile at the same time 

# Set end time & calculate runtime
$EndTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()
$TimeTaken = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime

# Write footer to log
Write-Output ($Footer = @"

   Start Time          : $StartTime
   End Time            : $EndTime
   Total runtime       : $TimeTaken
$("-"*79)
"@)

# Create logfile
Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append -InputObject $Footer

# Clean up variables at end of script
$Target=$StartTime=$EndTime=$OlderThanDays = $null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to write an "outer" script that passes the directory-to-be-cleaned, into the "inner" script, as a parameter.

For your "outer" script, have something like this:

```
$DirectoryList = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\DirList;
foreach ($Directory in $DirectoryList) {
    Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList ('"{0}\InnerScript.ps1" -Path "{1}"' -f $PSScriptRoot, $Directory);
}
```

**Note**: Using `Start-Process` kicks off a new process that is, by **default**, asynchronous. If you use the `-Wait` parameter, then the process will run synchronously. Since you want things to run more quickly and asynchronously, omitting the `-Wait` parameter should achieve the desired results.

### Invoke-Command

Alternatively, you could use `Invoke-Command` to kick off a PowerShell script, using the parameters: `-File`, `-ArgumentList`, `-ThrottleLimit`, and `-AsJob`. The `Invoke-Command` command relies on PowerShell Remoting, so that must enabled, at least on the local machine.

---

Add a parameter block to the top of your "inner" script (the one you posted above), like so:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $Path
)
```

That way, your "outer" script can pass in the directory path, using the `-Path` parameter for the "inner" script.

Comment: Thank you Trevor. I was also looking at Start-Job, which seems a bit similar. Is there also a way to limit it to only 3 or 4 directories being processed at the same time? Otherwise it might kill the server..

Comment: Check out the `Invoke-Command` command. It has the `-AsJob` and `-ThrottleLimit` parameters. These should help you control script execution. Keep in mind that `Invoke-Command` relies on PowerShell Remoting, so that has to be enabled at least locally.

Comment: Oops - disregard. The `-ThrottleLimit` parameter only throttles the systems that a script is being remotely deployed to. It doesn't throttle the objects that are being inputted to it.

Comment: Maybe it's even better with regards to load balancing to have the script run remotely with `Enter-PSSession` and use variables for server name and local path. But then I have to rewrite it completely and I need to know if PowerShell is a requirement to run this remotely.

Comment: On top of that, what is the fastest solution: deleting files by the UNC path or doing it in a remote session..

Comment: You're probably better off using PowerShell Remoting to kick off the script on the remote server. That way, the script will be running local to where the data is. Since these are simply file deletion operations, I can't imagine that it will be much faster running on the remote server, but you could do some performance testing to find out.

Comment: Yes Trevor, on remote with `Invoke-Command` it runs only 22 seconds instead of 30 minutes for over 10.000 files. Big win there I would say :) Thanks again for your help.